# How to make sidebar move with body when navbar clicked?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing Bootstrap with sidebars on left and right. Using that works great because for Bootstrap when on mobile it pushes body down. However that sidebar is not being pushed down because it styled with CSS not Bootstrap.

My html

```
    <!-- Left sidebar -->
     <div class="sidenav">
        <a class='active'">
              Home
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>

<!-- main content -->
    <div class="container-fluid mt-1 mt-sm-1 mt-md-3 mt-lg-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
          <v-fade-transition>
              <router-view></router-view>
          </v-fade-transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of main content -->
    <!-- Right sidebar -->
    <div class="sidenav">
        <a class='active'">
              Twitter
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

And css

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 150px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 160px;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  color: #1c465b;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform-origin: center;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

I want to execute the same behavior of body pushing down with sidebars.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `Bootstrap 4` navbar components. please go through [Navbar toggler](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) 
 Here is the working snippet of the behavior which you were looking for

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```